# How to add an existing work item to a board?

Tags: azure-devops

How do I add an existing work item to a the default board?

I can create work items under the `Work Items` section and I can also create work items by clicking **+ New Item** in the `Boards` section.

[image]

But how can I add an existing item to that board?

I cannot find a setting, field, option anywhere to do that.

*This is an organization Azure DevOps.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the board on what to be displayed.

[image]

By default, it's the Backlog items, so you will see the work items from your backlog (according to the sprints).

You can't just add a particular work item to the board.

See more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/kanban-basics?view=azure-devops).

Answer (score 4):

Your existing item needs to be "visible" to the board by existing in the appropriate iteration path and area path.

Without breaking out all the [organization settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/about-areas-iterations?view=azure-devops) that allow you to detail this stuff, the easy way to know the value you need to use is to create a new item on the board you want, and use the values it gets in `iteration path` and `area path` on the existing item.

### Illustrations:

Make sure your project has areas and iterations that make sense for you. Typically your project will start out with a root iteration path and three child iteration paths:

- Iteration 1
- Iteration 2
- Iteration 3

Iteration paths are used to handle both backlogs and sprints for teams.

[image]

The combination of area path and iteration path allows admins to divide sections of the global backlog among the teams that are doing the work.

[image]

Think of the connection like a grid. If the rows are iteration paths, then the areas are the columns that divide that row (or vise versa). Multiple teams can operate on the same row (iteration/backlog), but they will only see the work items that also fall inside their assigned columns (areas).

---

When you create a team the area can be created for you, or you can assign an area to a team after it is created.

[image]

You can also change the backlog iteration for a team.

[image]

Now your team has a board and a backlog. Again, for your first team, this is done for you.

[image]

You have obviously already created some work items, so you'll need to move them into the right area and iteration to make them show up.

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

### This can also be done in bulk from another team backlog

[image]
[image]
[image]